# How to pass c# type Guid type variable from ajax call parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've post method in my controller, it has Guid Type parameter as shown below

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDiscussion(Guid guid, string Title)
    {
        try
        {
           // some logics here
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = e }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

this is my ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Base/SaveDiscussion',
        data: {  guid: $("#DiscussionItemTempId").val(), Title: $(".discussionBox").val() },
        type: "post",
        success: function (response) {
           // some code here
        },
    });
```

I'm getting this exception as shown below in screenshot.
I think it's something wrong with Guid type parameter in controller

[image]

This is network tab status:

[image]

i've added debugger on my controller, its not hitting my controller so there is nothing wrong code inside my controller method, that's why i've not shown it

Comment: What does the server say the error is?  (ie when debugging the server) "500 Server Error" is a protection mechanism that hides the actual error, debugging the server should give you the real error.

Comment: The error means your controller code (that you did not show us) is throwing an exception

Comment: What exactly is being passed?  Check the browser network tab.

Comment: That 500 error could be caused by anything. I'd suggest setting a breakpoint in the C# code and stepping through it and debugging properly. You cold also check the response code from the request in the network tab of the console. You should see a more explanative exception message

Comment: Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response which will contain the details of the error

Comment: I've added breakpoint, actually its not hitting my controller

Comment: Ok, in which case use the network tools as Stephen and I described to find the exception message being thrown

Comment: Check the response of that network call which resulted in 500 status code. The response tab should tell you some details. My guess is that, your custom logic (which you have not shared) has some code which is crashing

Comment: Yup, controller is not throwing any exception. ajax call is not hitting it. that's why its giving 500 error. and i know 500 error is thrown by ajax call when it does not get method in controller with same name, same paramter name

Comment: sure, i'm sharing network call status too

Comment: Can you try changing the Guid type to string, then convert string to Guid.like this var realGuid = new Guid(string) ?

Comment: There is no reason to switch to string. Model binder can bind guid's fine as long as he is sending a valid guid value from the client side. He is getting 500 error because his custom logic is  probably crashing

Comment: Yes, it gives a 500 when it finds the action but the parameters are wrong, but the *error message* will tell you this.  Your application is hiding the error message and converting it to "server error". Try changing your web.config to show detailed errors, eg `<system.webServer><httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /></system.webServer>`

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha yes may be, it can be done but i was thinking that in converting from string to guid and guid to string might effect on actual value in guid variable

Comment: I've added network call status

Comment: You need to click on the **Response** tab (your currently showing the Headers tab)

Comment: You need to check the **response** tab for that call and read it yourself! That will give you details about the exception. If you see a message like "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'guid'", that means your ajax call is not sending a valid guid to server!

Comment: @freedomn-m as you can see in my ajax call, i've passed required parameters, it has nothing to do with viewmodel,

Comment: Your code will work fine as long as you pass a valid Guid value. See the working fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/SDHAWo

Comment: @Shyju but in my case Guid might be empty or we don't know value of it. or even its not generated for first time

Comment: If it is empty , then why do you use `Guid` as the parameter ? You may try switching to nullable Guid so your code will not crash when the request does not have a guid (i think this is the cause of your current 500 error)

Comment: @Shyju i tried to make it nullable but its giving me this error
**A value of type '<null>' cannot be used as a default parameter there are no standard conversions to type 'Guid'**

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for clarifying - hence the "correct me if I'm wrong" part :)  I'll remove those comments.

Answer (score 0):

Simply sending GUID as string works, since controller with a GUID param parses it automatically

```
data: {
    appID: '@Model.ID'
},
```

with 'ID' being a GUID type in the model